# Flip lines to form a diamond in python 3

Tags: python

The idea of this code is to enter a height and form a diamond with asterisks (stars).

eg. If the input for the height was 6, I'd want the code to produce:

```
************
*****  *****
****    ****
***      ***
**        **
*          *
**        **
***      ***
****    ****
*****  *****
************
```

I've gotten the top half so far and am wondering if it is possible to 'flip' lines horizontally.

```
height = int(input('Enter triangle height: '))
star = height
while star >= 1:
    a = int(star)*'*'
    b = int(2*height-2*star)*' '
    c = (height-star)*''
    d = star*'*'
    print(a, b,c,d,sep='')
    star = star - 1
star = height
while star >= 2:
    a = int(star)
    b = int(2*height-2*star)
    c = int((height-star))
    d = int(star)
    print(a*'*', b*' ',c*'',d*'*',sep='')
    star = star - 1`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second while loop to check if `star <= height`, and increment star from 2.

So it would look something like

```
star = 2
while star <= height:
    a = int(star)
    b = int(2*height-2*star)
    c = int((height-star))
    d = int(star)
    print(a*'*', b*' ',c*'',d*'*',sep='')
    star = star + 1
```

This is because you want to go from "small" to "large" so you need to do the inverse of the first while loop which decrements the amount of `*`'s.